# Connection string read from textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, textbox, database-connection

I'm trying to make my mysql connection string read from textbox instaid of direct string what i was trying to do is this

```
string myConnection = "datasource='" + this.label12 + "';username='" + this.textBox3 + "';password='" + this.textBox4 + "';SSL Mode=Required;Certificate Store Location=CurrentUser;";
```

And i get the error cannot connect to any mysql server

Coded in c#

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `label12` and `textBox3` directly, which implicitly calls `ToString()` on the object, and usually just returns the *type* of object (like "System.Windows.Controls.Label").

Use the `Text` property of your labels and text boxes. (I also used [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) for readability.)

```
var myConnection
    = string.Format("datasource='{0}';username='{1}';password='{2}';SSL Mode=Required;Certificate Store Location=CurrentUser;",
                    label12.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text);
```

I don't know if the connection string you're building will work. You may want to check out [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for samples.

Answer (score 1):

Please point out servername in connection string as pattern:

```
string myConnection
    = "Server="+myServerAddress+";Database="+myDataBase+";Uid="+myUsername+";Pwd="+myPassword;
```